# Calculate UTC time from given UTC time & number of seconds in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, utc

```
a=b+c;

result_utc_time= given_utc_time + given_number_of_seconds;
```

This is what I am trying to do. I want to calculate result_utc_time from given_utc_time & given_number_of_seconds

Let my `given_utc_time=2014-06-11T09:50:20Z`

```
given_number_of_seconds=1500
```

Does anyone know how to do this in PHP or in Javascript??

Comment: does date also need to be included in the time?

Comment: See my answer, i hope it's what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$given_utc_time='2014-06-11T09:50:20Z';    
$time = strtotime($given_utc_time);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+1500 second',$time));
```

or can use

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time+1500);
```

or using datetime:-

```
$date = new DateTime($given_utc_time);
$date->add(new DateInterval('PT1500S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: @TheJoker yes it's php var . you wants php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
$a = date('h:i:s A', strtotime('2:10:20')+36000);
```

then echo the `$a` somewhere.

So basically you need to adjust the '2:10:20' which I just placed there for a test to something you want. And the 36000 are the seconds it will increase it by.

So with 36000 it will add 10 hours to the time you gave. So this will output '`12:10:20 PM`'. The A after h:i:s adds the AM or PM, you can leave that out to get

`$a = date('h:i:s', strtotime('2:10:20')+36000);` this will echo '`12:10:20`'

Now you can also add variables to it:

```
$a = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($b)+$c);
```

and then for example:

```
$b = '2:10:20'; // The time
$c = 36000; //seconds to increase
```